# igraph cannot use GLPK

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, igraph, glpk

I just wrote a python script to do optimal_modularity using the igraph module, this function makes use of the GLPK library, but I'm getting this error even after installing python-glpk and practically all glpk related packages :

```
 root@ubuntu:/home/abdou/Desktop/graphs# python graph.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "graph.py", line 49, in <module>
    print g.community_optimal_modularity()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/igraph/__init__.py", line 1076, in community_optimal_modularity
    GraphBase.community_optimal_modularity(self, *args, **kwds)
NotImplementedError: Error at optimal_modularity.c:81: GLPK is not available, Unimplemented function call
```

This is the script :

```
    from igraph import *


g = Graph()

    g.add_vertex(1)
.
.
.
    g.add_vertex(20)

g.add_edge(1,2)

g.add_edge(12,0)

plot(g)
print g.community_optimal_modularity()
verClus = VertexClustering(g)

plot(verClus.cluster_graph())
```

Answer (score 2):

`python-igraph` depends on the igraph library, which is written in C. Depending on how you installed `python-igraph`, it *may* or *may not* be compiled with GLPK support. Since the code that uses GLPK from `python-igraph` is in the C layer, it does not matter if you install GLPK *after* the compilation of `python-igraph` or if you install `python-glpk`; the only thing that matters is whether GLPK was present on your machine when you *compiled* `python-igraph` for the first time.

So, assuming that you installed `python-igraph` using `pip` and you did not have the C core of igraph in advance on your machine, you will need to:

1. Uninstall `python-glpk` (it won't be needed).
2. Uninstall `python-igraph`.
3. Ensure that all the GLPK libraries are installed (make sure to install the development headers as well).
4. Reinstall `python-igraph`.

`python-igraph` should then detect that GLPK itself is installed (look for a line containing `GLPK support -- yes` or something similar in the early stages when `python-igraph` downloads the corresponding C core and tries to compile it) and you will be able to use `Graph.optimal_modularity()` from then on.

Comment: I followed the instructions, these are the GLPK packages I had before reinstalling igraph, but I'm still having the same problem. http://oi60.tinypic.com/mb61kw.jpg

Comment: Please post the full output of `pip install python-igraph` (after having uninstalled `python-igraph` first).

Answer (score 0):

I am using clustering methods and get membership instead. Hope this may help for MacOS user since I also had trouble with GLPK.